# Is aab's signature the same with apk file?

Tags: android, flutter, android-app-bundle, app-bundle

I'm making aab file for releasing.

We're using **flutter**.

Last release is uploading signed apk file to google play store,but this time for we can't upload 32bit and 64bit apk separately, so we tried to use **appbundle**.

**We do have signature when we release apk file.**

And because the release operation(upload apk file to google play) is handled by other team, so **I don't know whether I need to use a new signature for aab file's release.**

Here is my setting,just the same with last time

```
signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

and I have key.properties file

```
storePassword=XXX
keyPassword=XXX
keyAlias=XXX
storeFile=O:\\sourceCode\\key\\key.keystore
```

And for release, I set build variant as release, as introduced in [flutter official doc](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#how-do-i-build-a-release-from-within-android-studio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply "No" you don't need new signature to create app bundle. your old signature will work fine